# MomentJS - Grabbing the current time as a decimal value?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get the current time as a decimal value between 0 and 24

```
    const currentEpoch = moment().tz('America/Phoenix')
    const convertedEpoch = moment.unix(currentEpoch).format('hh:mm')
    const currentTimeAsNumeric = moment.duration(convertedEpoch).asHours();
```

for example.. `4:30pm` would be `16.5`

I keep getting variable numbers from the code I've tried above.

Answer (score 0):

from the https://momentjs.com/ docs you could do something very lightweight like:

parseFloat(moment().format("H")) + parseFloat(moment().format("mm")/60)